# Node.js script hangs when executed with sudo on Red Hat

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js script which executes some shell commands (using ShellJS). The script is supposed to be executed as a specific user. I'm using `sudo` to achieve this:
`sudo -u username script.js`

Everything works as expected when executed on Ubuntu or Debian. However, on Red Hat the script hangs inexplicably at this line:
`response = shell.exec('whoami', { silent: true });`
(Note that this only happens when trying to run it as a different user than the current one. Also, running a different command than `whoami` doesn't make a difference.)

Both node (v0.10.x) and npm are installed from the EPEL repo. Any idea what could be the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that AppArmor or SELinux are active and your app is prevented from calling `exec()`?